# Specification for vda formats

Tags: edi

I'm student and I have to make project which include EDI converter (mine of course). To be honest I have to use ODETTE format and VDA. Does anybody know where I can find any specification for this formats?

Any help would be great !:)

Answer (score 1):

ODETTE is edifact. see http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/welcome.html
all UN edifact messagges are there.
they have versions (like D 96A etc); so you have to be beware of the version of the message you use.

VDA is used in German automitive.
This is their website: http://www.vda.de/de/index.html
look eg at http://www.vda.de/de/publikationen/publikationen_downloads/index.html?aid=1
They have more than one format: edifact, csv, fixed elngth records.

Yes, you can build your own translator.
Take a look at Bots open source edi translator  (http://bots.sourceforge.net),
you might get some idea's ;-))